# If partials exist and are continuous then they are equal

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f$ be a real valued function on an open subset $E^2$. Prove that if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$ exist and are continuous then they are equal.

So I need to show that if the set $\{(x,y)\in E^2 : x\in[a,b], \ y\in[c,d]\}$ is entirely contained in the set in which $f$ is defined, then $$\int^b_a\left(\int^d_c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)dy\right)dx=\int^b_a\left(\int^d_c\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)dy\right)dx.$$

But I am not sure how I can continue the proof.

Comment: For a continuous integrand, you can change the order of integration.

Comment: @DanielFischer But how can I formally prove it using that since it is continuous we can change the order of integration?

Comment: My thought (not an official answer!!!) is that you should get the function $f(b,d)-f(a,c)$ on both sides if you evaluate them separately. But this doesn't show what you need it to show. The integrals you indicate would, to me, force some kind of constant as a result, not the equality of partials that you need, and I'd think you'd need to have things as $$\int_a^b \int_c^v ()dydx = \int_c^d \int_a^u ()dxdy$$ for some $v \in [c, d], u \in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left(\int_c^d \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx
&= \int_a^b \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,d) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,c)\right)\,dx\\
&= \bigl( f(b,d) - f(a,d)\bigr) - \bigl( f(b,c) - f(a,c)\bigr)\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to the continuous functions $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

On the other hand, since the continuity of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ allows changing the order of integration, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b \left(\int_c^d \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx
&= \int_c^d \left(\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy\\
&= \int_c^d \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(b,y) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,y)\right)\,dy\\
&= \bigl( f(b,d) - f(b,c)\bigr) - \bigl(f(a,d) - f(a,c)\bigr)\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

again by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

The commutativity of addition reveals $(1)$ and $(2)$ as equal.

For a continuous $g$, we have

$$\lim_{(b,d)\to(a,c)} \frac{1}{(b-a)(d-c)}\int_a^b\int_c^d g(x,y)\,dy\,dx = g(a,c),$$

and thus the equality of $(1)$ and $(2)$ shows

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(a,c) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(a,c),$$

and since $(a,c)$ was arbitrary, the equality of the mixed partial derivatives on $E^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice and concise proof!